# Eclipse: How to get TODOs from SQL and XML files in tasks

Tags: sql, xml, eclipse, comments, todo

In Java files I can write TODO comments and they show up in the Tasks window.

```
// TODO: Do something about this
```

However, when I write TODO comments in for example SQL scripts and XML files, they don't show up. Is there a way I can get them to do that? For example:

```
-- TODO: Fix this SQL query

<!-- TODO: Fix this XML -->
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Check your main Preference dialog for Task Tags pages.  Type "task" into the search box in the upper left of the dialog to help you find relevant pages.  For XML files, I know that that feature is off by default.

Comment: Didn't find a way to add SQL files to that list, but got it activated for XML files at least :)

Answer (score 8):

checkbox to activate :

Editors/structured text editors/task tags => check "Enable searching for task tags"

Answer (score 3):

Because a picture worth a thousand words :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `Add Task...` by right-clicking on the gutter of the editor.

[image: Add Task... screenshot]